# Regarding expressing $j_p $ as a polynomial in $\Phi $

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-function

[image][image]

I am self studying apostol Modular functions and Dirichlet series in Number Theory and I have a doubt in an argument of theorem 4.11 .

> I have posted two images and I hope both of them are clear. I posted them because it is very time consuming to write all details involving proof and also due to the fact that I have doubt only in last part of proof .
>
> Doubt is  - Function f is proved to be analytic at vertex $\tau $ =0 and each point $\tau $ =0 in H. ( I clearly understood it) .

But now I don't know how to deduce next line which is

> Therefore f is bounded in H so f is constant.

How does f becomes bounded in H?

Edit1 ->

> I am looking for an answer that doesn't involves Riemann surfaces.

Can someone please give some hint of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at the fundamental region of $\Gamma_0(p)$, it is the union of $ST^j(R)$ for $0\le j <p$, where $R$ is the fundamental region of $\Gamma$ and $S$ and $T$ are the usual $S\tau=-1/\tau$ and $\tau = \tau+1$. The only points of concern (*outside* $\mathbb H$) are easily seen to be $0$ and $\infty$.

As $f$ is automorphic for $\Gamma_0(p)$ and analytic in all $\mathbb H$ and in $\tau = 0$ it is enough to look at $\tau \to \infty$. But $\Phi(\tau)$ has a zero in $\tau=\infty$ looking the expression for $f$ if it is enough to check that $j_p(\tau)$ is bounded as $\tau \to \infty$ but then you can use the relation for $j_p(-1/\tau)$ on top of the first page you have quoted to see that it is also bounded as $\tau \to \infty$.

Comment: how you are sure that f is bounded for all values of $\tau $ except  possibly at i$\infty$ ( which is later proved to be bounded) ?

Comment: can you please answer the question asked by me above!!

Comment: I am awarding bounty to you as your answer is clear to me except 1 doubt and bounty is expiring in 7 hours. But please answer my doubt.

Comment: @InvisibleMan I am not sure where do you have the problem, Roughly: you know the function is analytic in all the plane (and so it is finite in all the plane). You also know that it is automorphic for $\Gamma_0(p)$, so for every $\tau\in \mathbb H$ there is a $\gamma\in \Gamma$ such that $\tau' = \gamma\tau \in R$ and $f(\tau')= f(\tau)$. Then it is enough to look at the fundamental region. Any unbounded sequence will have an increasing unbounded subsequence, which eithers converges to a finite point (cotradiction) or to 0 or $\infty$ (contradiction given the continuity of $f$ at both points).

Comment: thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is analytic on $\Bbb{H}$, it is $\Gamma_0(p)$ invariant and it is holomorphic at the two cusps $\Gamma_0(p)i\infty,\Gamma_0(p)0$. Covering the Riemann surface $X_0(p)=\Gamma_0(p)\setminus(\Bbb{H}\cup \Bbb{Q}\cup i\infty)$ by finitely many charts from $|s|\le 1$ we obtain that $f$ is bounded uniformly on $X_0(p)$, it attains its maximum modulus at some point $\Gamma_0(p)z$ and taking a chart $\phi(0)=z$ we obtain that $f\circ \phi$ is analytic and it attains its maximum modulus thus it is constant. By analytic continuation $f$ is constant.

Comment: Apostol never mentioned cusp forms till chapter -6and it's a part of chapter 4 .Isn't there a proof possible without using cusp ? If yes , can you please tell it .

Comment: There is no cusp form in my answer... No you can't do it without using the cusps. The cusps are the finitely many missing points on $\Gamma_0(p) \setminus \Bbb{H}$ where we ask that the functions are meromorphic (in the same way that an entire function can be complicated as $e^z$ but when asking it to be  meromorphic at $\infty$ then it has to be a polynomial).

Comment: can you explain it without using Riemann surfaces. I haven't studied them.